# Best practice to implement custom form control encapsulating multiple form inputs

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular17

I am using Angular 17 and would like to create a custom form control encapsulating multiple fields. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve. The input-text component is a third-party component relying on reactive forms for validation, and I need to use this component in my custom component.:

```js
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-custom-form-control',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="addressForm">
      <!-- Use third-party component for each field -->
      <input-text formControlName="street" placeholder="Street"></input-text>
      <input-text formControlName="city" placeholder="City"></input-text>
      <input-text formControlName="zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode"></input-text>
      <input-text formControlName="country" placeholder="Country"></input-text>
    </form>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressCustomFormControlComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressCustomFormControlComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class AddressCustomFormControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  addressForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addressForm = this.fb.group({
      street: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      zipcode: ['', Validators.required],
      country: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  // ControlValueAccessor methods

  // Validator method
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (this.addressForm.valid) {
      return null;
    } else {
      // Your custom validation logic, if needed
      return { customValidation: true };
    }
  }
}
```

My concern is that I have read that in the validate method of the Validator interface, the value of the control should only be accessed through the abstract control passed as a parameter to the method (namely through the `control.value` property), instead of directly accessing the internal properties of the component (such as the `addressForm` property).

My understanding is that this is due to the fact that the view that the parent control has of the custom control may not always reflect the internal state of the custom control, for example if the value change is triggered by external components. To a lesser extent, I have heard about the need to decouple the validate method from the concerns and implementation details of the ControlValueAccessor interface.

As a a result, I am really puzzled as I am trying to figure out the best practice / recommended pattern to achieve what I am after. Not being able to rely on an internal FormBuilder sounds like I would have to deal with a lot of boilerplate and reinvent the wheel every time. My specific questions are:

1. In Angular, what is the recommended design pattern to implement in this situation
2. Is there truly a risk that the parameter passed to the validate method could be out-of-sync with the internal state of the custom component?

Thank you